# Is it safe to hold on to exception objects?

Tags: c#, .net, exception, logging

I am creating a test logger which will include information about any exceptions that are thrown so that they can be displayed properly using a GUI.

Is it safe to use the following construct:

```
public class TestLogEntry {
    public System.Exception Exception { get; private set; }

    public TestLogEntry(/*...,*/ System.Exception exception = null) {
        //...

        Exception = exception;
    }
}
```

Or would the following be better?

```
public class TestLogEntry {
    public string StackTrace { get; private set; }
    public System.Type ExceptionType { get; private set; }
    public string ExceptionMessage { get; private set; }

    public TestLogEntry(/*...,*/ System.Exception exception = null) {
        //...

        if (exception != null) {
            StackTrace = exception.StackTrace;
            ExceptionType = exception.GetType();
            ExceptionMessage = exception.Message;
        }
    }
}
```

Whilst the first approach is more flexible (because it can contain additional custom data), here are my concerns:

- Holding on to exception object for a prolonged period.
- Using a lot of memory if exception objects are preventing large objects from being garbage collected.
- Exception returning wrong values when accessed out of context.

Q1. Are the above concerns valid?

Q2. Do exception objects typically reference a lot of other data?

Comment: Typically exception objects do not reference a lot of data. You should be ok holding on to your exception object for the duration of your logging code execution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Your concerns are valid:** exception objects might hold onto arbitrary other objects. This is very rare in practice. Actually I have never seen the `Exception.Data` property used. But I have seen an `Exception` derived class hold onto something big using custom fields: `WebException` has a `WebResponse` property!

So you see you might be keeping alive even something as expensive as an unmanaged resource.

I'd actually copy out the information and discard the `Exception`. Remember to also copy the `InnerException`.

A different concern might be that `Exception` is a **mutable type**. You can throw it at any time altering its stack trace. I'd like to capture its state just for that reason.

Also important is **memory usage**. Exception has some fields that are probably never used. You can save them. Also, inlining its fields into your log message object will eliminate the object header and object reference. A small gain but maybe worth taking in case of frequent exceptions.

Comment: Regarding WebResponse, the response stream may not be valid going forward.  So that should be taken into account.

Comment: That's a good point about capturing the inner exceptions also.

Answer (score 3):

Holding on to exceptions is fine.

In general they do not hold much data (stack trace, error message and associated data), but this is not a lot.

And one instance of an exception will not influence other instances even of the same type.

So:

> Holding on to exception object for a prolonged period.

No a problem.

> Using a lot of memory if exception objects are preventing large objects from being garbage collected.

Only an issue if you add lots of data to your exceptions - if you don't this is not an issue.

> Exception returning wrong values when accessed out of context.

Not sure what that means - what context? An exception is an exception.

Comment: > Exception returning wrong values when accessed out of context.
If the exception encapsulates some object and returns values based upon that object, where the said objects state is changed at a later stage rendering the exception information incorrect.

Comment: @LeaHayes this is possible, but I believe it to be not the best practise.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should realise that when you write "prolonged" or "a lot" these are relative rather than absolute terms, so nobody is going to be able to say whether these concerns are too much or not. I have 2Gb of RAM on my 10-core machine, and I deploy to Windows servers, so the memory implications would not bother me in the slightest. Perhaps you are running on an old Windows phone with only a few bytes of spare RAM. Who knows? If you are in doubt, profile your memory use, but I would be surprised if memory is an issue.

In general, a bigger concern for me would be that you might be tempted to use Exceptions as a way of displaying status messages to the user, which is not cool. Exceptions are for *exceptional* conditions. You might not even be able to recover from them meaningfully, let alone carry on as normal. Exceptions can be logged to a database (eg using log4net) if you want to keep records of them, but I think you would be better logging them rather than keeping them.

Comment: The exception messages and stack traces are relevant for my target audience (who themselves are programmers), but I do understand what you were suggesting.

Comment: Memory-wise I am concerned that an exception built-in to .NET or the library that we are using, may reference potentially very large objects in memory and thus keeping them "alive".